# Configure apache as proxy and remap one domain

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, mapping

For local test, I'm using Charles proxy, for those who don't know about it is a tool to debug HTTP requests. It can be configured to act as a proxy and intercept requests/responses and is able to do several things with it, like the most important for me, "remap" a domain to another.

It means that when I want set up the proxy on my mobile device and try to access `a.domain.tld` and `b.domain.tld` I can configure Charles to redirect transparently data to `c.domain.tld` and `d.domain.tld`.

This is what I want to do with Apache (preferably) (but suggestion are welcome).

I know a little about `mod_proxy` but I couldn't find any similar example, I bet I can do something with it while playing around with the rewrite mod, but I'm sure there is a simple thing to do.

What I want to do:

- Configure a vhost within apache called `proxy.domain.tld`
- It will act as any proxy **except** for the domain `a.domain.tld` and `b.domain.tld` for which it will target `c.domain.tld` and `d.domain.tld` respectively instead.

Any advices?

Comment: In other words: you want to set up a proxy that will transparently hijact certain requests and divert them to some other hosts?

Comment: @Laas, exactly, I want to test some live mobile application against a new code base

Answer (score 1):

Shooting from the hip, the `ProxyRemote` should be the thing you are looking for. The intent of that directive is to allow one proxy to forward some requests to next while serving others directly. Untested, but it should be possible to use this to your advantage:

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 1.2.3.4

  # Redirect these two domains to different destination
  ProxyRemote http://a.domain.tld http://c.domain.tld
  ProxyRemote http://d.domain.tld http://d.domain.tld
</Proxy>
```

**NB!**: Be sure to fill in some real IP numbers or other authentication, so you dont create yourself an open proxy.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I give it a try but I couldn't make the ProxyRemote directive work

Comment: Maybe set `LogLevel debug` and scan the logs to see what happens. I'm not exactly sure whether the `ProxyRemote` endpoints can be regular HTTP servers or must they be proxies themselves too.